# What is the proper way to toggle a switchClass in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui

#### Consider:

```
    <div id="obj" class="foo"><!-- --></div>
```

#### Expected:

What I'd like is to keep switching between class "foo" and "bar" on each mouse click.  Toggle class just seems to add and remove "bar", which isn't good enough.

I can accomplish the effect I want with using a combination of `.hasClass()`, a ternary condition, and `switchClass`, but I'd like to see how others would accomplish this - I'm trying to increase my experience with jQuery.

***[This](http://www.pedrocorreia.net/mySnippets/javascript/jQuery-Switch-Replace-Change-Class-Name)*** may be what I want, but I'm also trying to reduce external plugins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I get you right, you might just want to use `.toggleClass()`.

```
$('#obj').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('foo bar');
});
```

Ref.: [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/sTBcb/

Comment: That's brilliant! I hadn't thought of doing it that way.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  I've tried `toggleClass` before, but did not know you can do it this way, even after reading the docs, +1!  So anything that's currently in the class is replaced by anything in the list: `class="a foo z baz"` and the toggle was `"foo bar foobar baz"`, then the new class would be `class="a z bar foobar"`; good to know.  The one thing I'm worried about is the order of the class listing - both switchClass and toggleClass seem to append to the end, rather than replace the actual order.